# Android camera intent does not return to onActivityResult

Tags: image, android-intent, camera

I am trying to save a full camera image to a specified Uri when passing the uri to the camera intent. But it does not return to onActvityResult. However, I have tried getting the image using Bundle in the onActivityResult but it returns a thumbnail. I have tried lots of tutorials and they all had this problem. Can u please help!!!

```
            Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File u = getTempFile();
            picUri = Uri.fromFile(u);
            camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(u));

            startActivityForResult(camera, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

onActivityResult

```
            if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK  && null != data) 
            {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n"+picUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: haven't found any solution for this yet. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try code given below :

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA); 


                protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                      if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

                      File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      .toString());

                 for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                      }
                    }

                String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
     } }

   }
```